# How does the NOT IN logical operator work to generate this output?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following tables and data: [**Screenshot of the data here**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wwkK9.png)

```
course:
course#     ctitle               units
---------   -------------------  -----
ACCT 201    Financial Account      3
CHEM 356    Organic Chemistry      4
HIST 101    US History             5
MINS 235    Database Design        4
MINS 301    Intro to Business IS   3
MINS 350    Systems Analysis       4
PHED 434    Advanced Gym           2

class:
class#  course#      sec#   semyr
------  ----------   -----  -----
203     ACCT 201       03    F11
204     ACCT 201       04    F11
307     MINS 301       07    F11
418     MINS 235       04    F11
438     MINS 350       01    F11
624     PHED 434       02    F11

student:
sid  sname       major
---  ----------  ----------
 1    Bob        MINS
 2    Mary       POMG
 3    Joe        MGMT
 4    Sue        MKTG
 5    Jim        ACCT

class_student:
class  sid   grade
-----  ----  -----
 203     2     B
 203     5     D
 204     1     C
 204     4     C
 307     1     B
 307     2     B
 307     4     A
 418     1     A
 418     2     B
 418     5     C
 438     1     B
 438     4     C
 634     5     F

grade:
grade  grade_pts
-----  ---------
  A        4
  B        3
  C        2
  D        1
  F        0
```

When I run the following query:

```
SELECT      *  
FROM        STUDENT 
WHERE       SID NOT IN 
            (   SELECT  SID 
                FROM    CLASS_STUDENT 
                WHERE   GRADE IN ('A' , 'B')
            ) 
ORDER BY    SID;
```

I think Oracle would generate this output.

```
sid sname major
--- ----- -----
 1  bob   mins
 4  sue   mktg
 5  jim   acct
 5  jim   acct
 5  jim   acct
```

I would like to understand how NOT IN logical operator works. How does the `NOT IN` operator work in the above query to generate the output?

Comment: is this homework? if so, then it should be tagged as such

Comment: Sql is valid, and if the requirement was for all those students who received a C or Lower for their major, then it's correct. Don't go mad with it though, IN isn't brilliant, Not IN is worse.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT SID FROM CLASS_STUDENT WHERE GRADE IN ( 'A' , 'B' )
```

will select the sid of the students having A,B grades.
will result in a list of sid

```
SID
2
1
2
4
1
2
1
```

then

```
SELECT  *  FROM STUDENT 
WHERE   SID NOT IN  ...
```

will result in :

```
SID     sname       Major
3       joe         mgmt
5       jim         acct
```

Answer (score 3):

It returns students with grades worse than `B`.

`NOT IN` filters out what you define after that.

In words:

> select all student but not the ones that have grades `A` or `B`

Comment: Great! thanks for the help, would identical rows also be selected? or Would Oracle weed those out?

Comment: @user1368186: No. It selects all entries from your `student` table that does not match the subselect. Since your student table does not have any duplicates there are none selected.

Answer (score 1):

The subquery `(SELECT SID FROM CLASS_STUDENT WHERE GRADE IN ( 'A' , 'B' ))` selects the SIDs of all students that have an A or B grade in at least one class.  When used with an `IN` operator, the list is implicitly deduplicated.  It appears in your data that students 1, 2, and 4 all have an A or B in at least one class, so would be included in the result set of this subquery.

Then, the full query is simply selecting all rows from `STUDENT` that are not included in the list returned by the subquery.  So I think you are getting two rows, with SIDs 3 and 5.

Your "expected result" makes little sense.  There is no reason to expect multiple rows for the same student when your query is selecting all students then filtering some out.

What your query is doing is showing students that don't have an A or B grade in at least one class.  I suspect that what you want is to show each student-class combination for which the grade is worse than a B (that seems consistent with your expected result).  To do this, I would suggest driving the query off of the `CLASS_STUDENT` table, and joining to `STUDENT` to get the student information (and perhaps to `CLASS` and `COURSE` to get the name of the course, if desired).

Comment: Thank you, i was having a hard time grasping that concept. So, in this case the expected result would be sid 5 jim and acct.